# tabbedBar, showing different views titanium

Tags: titanium-alloy

Here is my code for tabbed bar:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
                <TabbedBar id="bb1" platform="ios" backgroundColor="#369" top="50" height="25" width="200">

                    <!-- The Labels tag sets the TabbedBar.labels property. -->
                    <Labels>

                        <!-- Specify text with node text or the title attribute. -->
                        <!-- Can also specify the enabled, image and width attributes. -->

                        <Label>One</Label>
                        <Label>Two</Label>
                        <Label>Three</Label>

                    </Labels>

                    <!-- Place additional views for the TabbedBar here. -->
                    <Views>
                    <View backgroundColor='red'>1</View>
                    <View>2</View>
                    <View><Label>Does this work!</Label></View>
                    </Views>

                </TabbedBar>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

When I click on a tab, how can I make sure that the view corresponds to the button pressed - I know how to do this in titanium but not alloy.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. I'm sure there must be a better way but I couldn't see anything in the documentation, this was my solution:

```
var animation = require('alloy/animation');

var previousIndex = $.tabbedBar.getIndex();
$.tabbedBar.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var currentIndex = $.tabbedBar.getIndex();
    var viewArr = [];

    viewArr[0] = $.view1;
    viewArr[1] = $.view2;
    viewArr[2] = $.view3;

    animation.crossFade(viewArr[previousIndex], viewArr[currentIndex], 700)

    previousIndex = currentIndex;

});
```

EDIT:
(In case you don't know, on Android there's a module to give you similar functionality: https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/viewpager but check issue #5 on the original repo as you'll have to incorporate that into any build. On the Android version, you don't need to handle the clicks yourself.)